# Load a single module of page in views codeigniter framework

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am developing a web app using codeigniter framework. My application has a fixed header and footer.I want to middle section (ie the body) of my application to load when the user goes to various pages which are available to him and make the header and footer constant.

(hackerrank.com ... I was talking about a website similar to this one ... **after login** into this website ... the header and the sidebar of this remains constant and they load the remaining page ... how can we implement it using CI framework)

Is there any way through which I can achieve this?

I am performing the following actions which is making me to load the complete website(Its like reloading the entire page :/)

As You can see the following code is present in my template.php

```
<?php 

        $this->load->view("templates/header.php");

        $this->load->view($main_body);  

        $this->load->view("templates/footer.php");
?>
```

and I Controller I write the following piece of code usually

```
   public function load_page(){

            $data['main_body'] = 'dashboard_pages/dashboard_view';

            $this->load->view('template.php',$data);
     }
```

Comment: If you don't want to reload the whole page, you're looking for AJAX. But you have not asked about it.

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/ ... I was talking about a website similar to this one ... after login ... the header and the sidebar of this remains constant and they load the remaining page ... how can we implement it using CI framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close to the solution: Load the header and the footer as they are, variables:

```
<?php 
        $this->load->view($header);    
        $this->load->view($main_body);      
        $this->load->view($footer);
?>
```

The tricky thing, is that you're always writing the method function load_page() in every controller you write, and it would be better having a MY_controller, a class previous to your controller class in which you'll write which footer you're referring:

Check for writing a MY_Controller here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

Then, write your MY_Controller:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function load_page( $page )
    {            
        $data['main_body'] = $page;

        // Logic for your header or footer deppending on logging or whatever...
        if ( 1 ==1 ) {
            $data['header'] = "templates/header.php";
            $data['footer'] = "templates/footer.php";
        }

        $this->load->view('template.php',$data);
    }
}
```

and you'll have to make sure your controllers extends MY_Controller class, and add a load_page method to whom you'll pass the argument:

```
class Custom_page extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load_page( 'dashboard_pages/dashboard_view' );
    }
}
```

I think with that you'll have exactly what you look for, that way you only have to write in one place the logic for the header and footer: In MY_Controller, and just use it in any part.